# The ConnectionString property has not been initialized. Winforms C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am in the process of adding a new form to an already established Winforms application.

I have a DataGridView on my form and the relevant method in code behind which calls my dbAPI DataTable method. I have written the method with exactly the same code as many others used in the dbAPI class but for some reason it is not initialising the connection string...

```
 public DataTable getMyTable()
    {
        //used for populating the DataGridView
        SqlCommand _com = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select * from tab.myTable where Country = 'Angola' "), _conn);
        _com.CommandTimeout = _command_timeout;

        DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter _adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            _adapt.SelectCommand = _com;
            int i = _adapt.Fill(_ds, "Asset_Transactions");
            if (_ds.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                return _ds.Tables[0];
            }
            else
            {
                return makeErrorTable("GetMyTable", "No Table Returned for myTable");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return makeErrorTable("GetMyTable", e.Message);
        }
    }
```

_conn is an SQLConnection object. My connection string is in the app.config...

```
  class dbAPI
{
    Utils _utils = new Utils();

    //this is the API between the Application Code and the LDB Database
    string _ldb_connection_string = (string)dii.Properties.Settings.Default.connLDB; //connection string but with only one \ in settings as it gets converted to \\
    int _command_timeout = Convert.ToInt32((string)dii.Properties.Settings.Default.commandTimeOut); //Command time out
    SqlConnection _conn = new SqlConnection();

    public dbAPI()
    {
        //constructor
    }

    #region --------------- Database Connectivity Section
    public string openLocalDatabaseConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            //try to create the connection
            _conn = new SqlConnection(_ldb_connection_string);
            _conn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return string.Concat("Can't connect to LDB with '", e.Message, "'");
        }

        return ""; //success
    }
    public string closeLocalDatabaseConnection()
    {
        _conn.Close();
        _conn.Dispose();

        return "";
    }
```

I am getting an empty connection string and 'The ConnectionString property has not been initialized' exception thrown. I don't understand as I have numerous other methods in the class which work without issue. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: well where do you initialize `_conn`?? That's probably the part worth showing

Comment: like jonesy said _conn.Open().....probably

Comment: debug it and see if it's set/what it is when the error is thrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call openLocalDatabaseConnection() function before proceeding further so that your SqlConnection Object will be initilised with Connection String Properly.

Code :

```
        public DataTable getMyTable()
        {           
            openLocalDatabaseConnection();
            //used for populating the DataGridView
            SqlCommand _com = new SqlCommand(string.Format("select * from tab.myTable where Country = 'Angola' "), _conn);
            _com.CommandTimeout = _command_timeout;

            DataSet _ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter _adapt = new SqlDataAdapter();
            try
            {
                _adapt.SelectCommand = _com;
                int i = _adapt.Fill(_ds, "Asset_Transactions");
                if (_ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                {
                    return _ds.Tables[0];
                }
                else
                {
                    return makeErrorTable("GetMyTable", "No Table Returned for myTable");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return makeErrorTable("GetMyTable", e.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou my friend! I stupidly didn't call the method in my form.cs class. Learning everyday...

Answer (score 0):

For example add an application config file to your project(or inside the one you have) and place this(the name and the connection string you place yours of course):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="MyConnection" connectionString ="your connection string here"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then in your _ldb_connection_string:

```
string _ldb_connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
```